# I need the name of an electrical spring switch with a thin rod inside that completes a circuit upon impact

Tags: switches, spring

I had a transparent ball that lit up when you bounced it. Inside it had a tall thin stiff spring, and inside the spring was a metal rod. When the ball bounced, the spring moved to contact the rod and completed the circuit.  I could probably create something like it but would rather buy a commercial version. Googling has not helped me even find a matching picture.

Comment: Most of them I see use an open coil spring constrained at one end with a mass at the other end. There's a rod or pin up the middle of the spring. The spring flexes orthogonally to the winding axis and makes contact with the inner rod when acceleration occurs. No ball. The ball type switches are sometimes used as a replacement for the old and very reliable (but toxic) Hg tilt switches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "vibration sensor spring".

Comment: They call it a "trembler" in The Rock: https://youtu.be/CrFUjbB6FPg?feature=shared

Answer (score 2):

These replies gave me enough information to look up the right thing. I'm holding one in my hand now! "Spring Electronic Vibration Sensor Switch".

Comment: [Saying “thanks” is appreciated, but it doesn’t answer the question.](/help/how-to-answer)